# $a=\frac{b×(3c-5)}{15}$ and $a,b,c$ are numbers from $S$, prove that S has infinitely many elements.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a question from my exam and I don't really know how to solve it.

Let S be the set of positive integers such that for $a$ is any number from S, there exist two numbers $b$ and $c$ also from S such that:

$a=\frac{b×(3c-5)}{15}$

Prove that the set S has infinitely many elements.

And this is what I have done:
If $3c-5$ is divisible by $15$
Then $3c-5$ is divisible by $5$ and $3$
$ \rightarrow c$ is divisible by $5$
$ \rightarrow c = 5k \rightarrow 3c-5=5\times{3k-1}$ which is not divisible by $3$
So b must divisible by $15$

Comment: It's considered bad form here to post a question with no indication of where it comes from, why you are interested in it, what progress you made on it, where you got stuck, and so on. Questions like this often get closed and deleted quickly. Also, it doesn't look like set theory to me, maybe algebra, maybe elementary number theory. Please improve the question and the tag.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: $b$ doesn't have to be divisible by $15$, but it must be divisible by $3$. E.g., $a=2$, $b=3$, $c=5$.

Comment: As @GerryMyerson points out, $b$ must be divisible by $3$. Note that we know $15 \mid b(3c-5)$, which implies at least one of $b, 3c-5$ is divisible by $3$, and at least one is divisible by $5$. Clearly $3 \nmid 3c-5$, but if $c=5k$, then $5 \mid 3c-5$.

Comment: Now with $3 \mid b$ in mind, what can you glean from this rearrangement: $$5(3a+b)=3bc$$

Comment: I have an idea is to prove it by using reduction and absurdum.
Suppose that a can be divisible by $3^m$ but cannot be divisible by $3^{m+1}$

Comment: I think we need to use the Lifting-the-exponent lemma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to find all the whole solutions of the following equation :

$15a=b(3c-5)$

Since $\;3\mid b(3c-5)\;$ and $\;3\not\mid(3c-5)\;,\;$ then $\;3\mid b\;,\;$ hence $\;b=3b_1\,.$

Consequently, we get that

$15a=3b_1(3c-5)\;\;,$

$5a=b_1(3c-5)\;.$

There are two possible cases : $\;5\mid b_1\;$ or $\;5\mid(3c-5)\;.$

***First case :***$\;5\mid b_1$

If $\;5\mid b_1\;,\;$ then $\;b_1=5b_2\;,$

$5a=5b_2(3c-5)\;\;,$

$a=b_2(3c-5)\;.$

***Second case:***$\;5\mid(3c-5)$

If $\;5\mid(3c-5)\;,\;$ then $\;5\mid c\;,\;$ hence $\;c=5c_1\;,$

$5a=b_1(3\cdot5c_1-5)\;\;,$

$5a=5b_1(3c_1-1)\;\;,$

$a=b_1(3c_1-1)\;.$

Therefore, all the whole solutions of the equation are the following ones :

$\begin{cases}
a=\lambda(3\mu-5)\\
b=15\lambda\\
c=\mu
\end{cases}\qquad\lor\qquad\begin{cases}
a=\lambda(3\mu-1)\\
b=3\lambda\\
c=5\mu
\end{cases}$

for any $\;\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb Z\;.$

For any $\;\lambda,\mu>1\;,\;$ we get infinitely many positive solutions of the equation.

Now I am going to prove that the set $\;S\;$ has infinitely many elements.

Since $\;3\mid b\;,\;$ there exist $\;n,\beta_1\in\mathbb Z^+\;$ such that $\;b_1=b=3^n\beta_1\in S\;$ and $\;3\not\mid\beta_1\;.$

Moreover,

$b_1=3^n\beta_1=\lambda(3\mu-5)\quad\lor\quad b_1=3^n\beta_1=\lambda(3\mu-1)\;.$

Since $\;3\not\mid(3\mu-5)\;$ and $\;3\not\mid(3\mu-1)\;,\;$ it follows that

$\lambda=3^n\lambda^*\;$ where $\;\lambda^*\in\mathbb Z^+\;$ and $\;3\not\mid\lambda^*\;.$

Consequently ,

$b_2=15\lambda=3^{n+1}\cdot5\lambda^*\in S\quad\lor\quad b_2=3\lambda=3^{n+1}\lambda^*\in S\;.$

In any case ,

$b_2=3^{n+1}\beta_2\in S\;$ where $\;\beta_2\in\mathbb Z^+\;$ and $\;3\not\mid\beta_2\;.$

By proceeding analogously, we get an infinite sequence of different elements of $\;S\;$ that is :

$b_k=3^{n+k-1}\beta_k\in S\quad$ for all $\;k\in\mathbb Z^+\;,$

where $\;\beta_k\in\mathbb Z^+\;$ and $\;3\not\mid\beta_k\quad$ for any $\;k\in\mathbb Z^+\;.$

Hence the set $\;S\;$ has infinitely many elements.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your proof. You showed that there can be inifinitely many solutions, i.e. an infinite $S$ is possible. But how does it follow that you need inifinitely many elemnts, i.e. that  a finite $S$ is not possible?

Comment: @Toffomat, I have already written in my answer why it is not possible that the set $\;S\;$ is finite.

Comment: Ah, your edit makes it clear.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $S$ is finite, then there exists $m$ such that $3^m$ is the largest power of $3$ that divides any element of $S$.

Therefore there exists $a, b, c, d \in S$ such that $a = 3^m d$ and $15 a=b*(3c-5)$.

It follows that $3^{m+1}*5d=b*(3c-5)$ and since $3 \nmid (3c-5)$ we have $3^{m+1} \mid b$.

This contradicts the definition of $m$ hence $S$ cannot be finite.

Note strictly speaking $S$ could be the empty set. Also note $S$ is not unique. Any set than contains $2$ and is closed under multiplication by $15$, will have the desired property. You can show $S$ must contain $2$.